# How to get the value of TextView from position int in a ListView?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, textview

I have a `Button` which when clicked will execute an `addQty` method and in this method I need to set the value of a `TextView` on the same line as the `Button` was pressed. I have the `position` integer available to me but I cannot work out how to get the `TextView`.
I have a custom `ArrayAdapter` which sets this in the `getView` method:

```
ImageButton plus = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.qtyPlus);
plus.setTag(position);
```

My layout then does the following:

```
<ImageButton
   android:id="@+id/qtyPlus"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:src="@drawable/plus"
   android:onClick="addQty" />
```

My `addQty` method:

```
public void addQty(View v) {
        int position = Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString());

        Item tmp = (Item)adapter.getItem(position);
        Log.d("MyApp",tmp.getName());

}
```

This works as I am able to get the item object of the clicked row in the list, but how do I now set a `TextView` value in that `ListView` row?

Comment: I didn't understand the question. Could you please format it properly? What is your requirement ? According to tile You need the value in the textview which is present at specific position. Every adapter will be connected with a Collection Object which contains the complete information of every row. You can get the data t any row position by using that collection object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't set a new `TextView` value for that list row directly, instead you update the `Item` element with the new value and then call `notifyDataSetChanged()`(on the adapter object) to notify the adapter that you modified something and that it should update the `ListView`.